# JavaScriptでブラウザを判定して異なるページにリダイレクトする方法

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptでブラウザのUAを判定しているページから、さらにリダイレクトすることは可能でしょうか？
非対応ケータイ、対応ケータイで別にページを振り分けたいのです。

1.　ページに飛んで来て、まずUAを判定する
2.　0秒ですぐリダイレクトする(Aだったらこっち、Bだったらこっち)

クリックなどの動作なしには無理なのでしょうか。
質問がわかりずらく申し訳ないですがお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

可能です。`window.location.href`で飛ばせば良いです。（ループしないように　リダイレクトを設定して下さい。）
例、ja.stackoverflow.com　のいろいろな所へ飛ばす場合

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
if(ua.indexOf('iPhone') > 0 || ua.indexOf('iPod') > 0 || ua.indexOf('Android') > 0 && ua.indexOf('Mobile') > 0){
    //スマホのとき
    window.location.href = "https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions";

}else if(ua.indexOf('iPad') > 0 || ua.indexOf('Android') > 0){
    //タブレットのとき
    window.location.href = "https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags";
}else{
    //?
    window.location.href = "https://ja.stackoverflow.com";
}
```